# Displaying only selected headers in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, .net-2.0

How can I display only selected headers in DataGridView control?
For example I have DataTable with headers ("Name","Age","Status"), but I'd like to omit "Age" column when displaying.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the DataBindingComplete() method:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Age"].Visible = false;
```

ref: [How to: Hide Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c24a0d7.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd probably add the columns that I do want manually (`AutoGenerateColumns=false`), rather than try to take away the ones I don't want.

If this was a class model (rather than `DataTable`) you can do things like setting `[Browsable(false)]` on properties you never want to see. <s>With `DataTable` I wonder if you can't do something with a non-default `DataView`...</s>. Other than that, you simply just Add the columns you want.